# In Stackoverflow Careers, listing's 'tags' aren't filtered out by search term exclusions

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I put "tags" in quotes because these are not actual tags but I don't know what to call them [see screenshot below].

[image: screenshot of job listing page with the word senior]

The [listing](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/96903/full-stack-javascript-engineer-syrinx-consulting-corporation), shown in the screenshot, was found as a result of the following query: [**-senior -sr -[senior]**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=-senior%20-sr%20-[senior]&location=Boston%2C%20MA&range=100&distanceUnits=Miles)

I would expect the results to respect my excluded term ie. by filtering out any listing that had that term at all.

Comment: Looking into this now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We weren't including the seniority tags in the body of text we use for searching.

However, depending on what side of an A/B test you're currently on then you may not see any result from using the negation (-) operator. We're hoping to enable that functionality for all users very soon.

Stay tuned!

Thanks for the report :)